# Ubuntu: reboot "Failed to talk to init daemon" after 15.04 -> 15.10 update

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I had a fully patched 15.04 installation and did the do-release-update. It's a VM with a popular US hoster, I have root and have performed earlier similar upgrades on this machine with no problems. At the end of the update I was advised to reboot, as usual, so I just entered "reboot" but only got the message in the title and am back at the prompt.

I have Plesk access to the container so thought I'd reboot from there - bad mistake: after the shutdown nothing came up and I couldn't even SSH in. The tech support guys "did something to MySQL" (sorry to be vague, that's all I got) and I'm back up now. However, I think I'm back in the same situation because trying "reboot" just gives the same "Failed to talk to init daemon" message.

The server seems stable enough in that it is serving sites OK, but I'm not happy with is being so fragile. I can't now update my kernel, amongst other things.

What the heck happened during this update?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this was down to the VM image the hosting provider was running not being fully compatible with 15.10. I'm sure this isn't a widespread Ubuntu issue.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to fix the compatibility issue? Or did you just reinstall and start from scratch? I'm facing the same thing right now on a VPS.

Comment: I ditched them completely. And it was because of this, actually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's a shame. Mine is still usable, sort of. When I reboot it, none of the services start. I have to login via console and start them all. So things are functional, as long as it doesn't reboot. I'll probably back it up, reinstall 14.04 (their image) and upgrade back to vivid.

Comment: That's exactly what I had - all services were manually startable, but I then found MySQL died every few days whereas it didn't before the update. There was no way I could continue like that.